# How to use AutoIT for handling multiple authentication windows with different credentials?

Tags: selenium2, cross-browser-testing

I am writing the test script in `java` using `selenium webDriver`.

I have a situation where while executing the test script different authentication windows will appear and might need different credentials.

For example when I open a url, a 'Authentication Required' window appears. Say this wants "uid1" and "pass1" as credentials. And when another link on that page is clicked anther 'Authentication Required' window appears and this needs "uid2" and "pass2" as credentials.
In both authentication windows the title is same but the text is different.

How to handle this using `AutoIT`? Can anyone please post a sample code or guide me through this?

Answer (score 1):

If the order in which you spawn the windows is known, can you capture the handle value from the first window and then assume that the second window is the one that doesn't match that handle.

I am rusty on AutoIt so I didn't put any code, but I did use the [oh so cool window info tool](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) to get the values I would try to use. It's a life saver in situations like this.

First window:

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Authentication Required
Class:  MozillaDialogClass
Position:   2376, 597
Size:   453, 167
Style:  0x16C80084
ExStyle:    0x00000101
Handle: 0x000000000004097E #this appears unique, but not predictable
```

Second window:

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Authentication Required
Class:  MozillaDialogClass
Position:   2376, 597
Size:   453, 167
Style:  0x16C80084
ExStyle:    0x00000101
Handle: 0x000000000005097E #this appears unique, but not predictable
```

Essentially first window == 0x000000000004097E , second window <> 0x000000000004097E

Alternately, you can do each operation in a different browser and use the Title and/or Class to distinguish them.

First Window in FireFox:

```
>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Authentication Required
Class:  MozillaDialogClass 
Position:   2387, 597
Size:   432, 167
Style:  0x16C80084
ExStyle:    0x00000101
Handle: 0x000000000004097E
```

Second Window in Internet Explorer:

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Windows Security
Class:  #32770
Position:   2234, 634
Size:   439, 253
Style:  0x96C80A84
ExStyle:    0x00010101
Handle: 0x00000000000507EA
```

Comment: Hi Lucas Schwarz,
The windows might appear at different times. Both the authentication windows might not appear at the same time. We could not predict it.